# Prevent browser from sending Expect header?

Tags: http, browser, http-headers, language-lawyer

I am writing an embedded web server, and want to avoid unnecessary protocol aspects, to save limited flash memory. Is there a universal way to prevent browsers from sending the `Expect:` header when uploading a file?

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect:

> No common browsers send the Expect header, but some other clients such
> as cURL do so by default.

Does such language imply that *future versions* of common browsers will also not send the Expect header? If not, how would I prevent them from doing so?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is use HTTP/1.0. It's not uncommon for embedded devices to use HTTP/1.0, allowing them to implement a much simpler subset of HTTP. As far as I know, every relevant client still supports this.

Comment: For what it's worth, [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.20) says: "A server that does not understand or is unable to comply with any of the expectation values in the `Expect` field of a request MUST respond with appropriate error status. The server MUST respond with a 417 (Expectation Failed) status if any of the expectations cannot be met or, if there are other problems with the request, some other 4xx status."

Comment: @Evert Yes, HTTP/1.0 is perfectly well supported by relevant clients, as you note. However, `Expect` is sent before the initial server response (that includes the HTTP/1.x string), so I don't see how this could work.

Comment: @Igor Are you saying that the client is required to resend the request if it receives Expectation Failed? Even if this were the case, I would prefer if there were a way to prevent the browser from sending `Expect` in the first place. For example, in `curl -T <file>`, one can do `-Hexpect:`.

Comment: @personal_cloud, I think you are allowed to respond to a HTTP/1.1 request with a HTTP/1.0 answer.

Anyway, there's no way to inform a client to not use `Expect`, because there's no real communication between server and client before a client sends those bytes.

Comment: Well, barring a time machine or some other way to reverse causality, I don't see what you can do now to prevent some future, as yet unwritten, browser from sending something to your server.

Comment: @Igor a specification could be defined, and future browsers might decide to comply with it. I.e., the same way that we expect any other behavior of future browsers.

Comment: @Evert The suppression option would be in the javascript code running on the client, not something sent by the server of course (as you noted). Maybe there is some option in the XmlHttpRequest object to control the request headers, for example. Perhaps `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()`. But Mozilla's description doesn't seem to clatify whether this option would override a hypothetical `Expect:` generated by a future browser. So I guess this is a language-lawyer question.